# Resizing start behaving inaccurate after starting loop of scrolling

Tags: ios, image, uiscrollview, resize

i got images scrollview and i am trying to change the size of views while scrolling, it works correct first time but when i started loop of scrolling means setting contentoff 0, 0, then it will start behaving inaccurate, means it started shuffeling views, up and down, it is working fine while scrolling upwards. if anyone get the problem please guide me where i am doing wrong? or suggest me any tutorial. HERE IS MY CODE.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{



  if (IS_IPHONE5)
         scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, ((count*142)+710));
     else
         scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, ((count*130)+530));
     makecopy= tableArray.count+4;
        for(int i=0;i<=makecopy;i++)
        {
            if(i==0)
                yValue=0;
            else
                yValue=130;

            UIView* view1;
            //=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (i*130)+yValue, 320, 260)];
            if (IS_IPHONE5) {


                if (i!=0/*&&i!=count*/){
                    yValue=142;
                    view1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (i*142)+yValue, 320, 284)];
                }
               else{
                    yValue=0;
                        view1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (i*142)+yValue, 320, 284)];
                }
  }
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {


 if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
  {
     if (normalScroll)
     {
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
           // NSLog(@">:%i  %i:<",(i*142),((i+1)*142));
            if (scroller.contentOffset.y>=(i*142)&&scroller.contentOffset.y<((i+1)*142)){
                [self doscrollingwiththView:[scroller viewWithTag:i+1] view2:[scroller viewWithTag:i+2] view3:[scroller viewWithTag:i+3] view4:[scroller viewWithTag:i+4]];
            }

        }

        changeMe = true;

        if (!isUp && scrollView.contentOffset.y>(count*142)) {
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,  0)];
            changeMe = false;
        }

        if (isUp && scrollView.contentOffset.y<= -1) {
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,  (count*142)-10)];
            changeMe = false;
        }
 }

-(void)doscrollingwiththView:(UIView*)view1 view2:(UIView*)view2 view3:(UIView*)view3 view4:(UIView*)view4
{

  // NSLog(@"view1 : %@ view1 : %@ view1 : %@ view1 : %@ ",view1,view2,view3,view4);
  offsetY=offsetY1+ scroller.contentOffset.y;
  int view1Y=0;
  int view2Y=0;
  //int view3Y;
  //int view4Y;
   if (IS_IPHONE5)
  {
    view2Y=284;
  }
   else
  {
    view2Y=260;
    //view3Y=390;
    //view4Y=520;
  }

 for(int i=0;i<makecopy;i++)
  {
    if (IS_IPHONE5) {
       // NSLog(@"the value is: %i  the contentoffset is:%f",(142*i),scroller.contentOffset.y);
        if(scroller.contentOffset.y>=(142*i)&&scroller.contentOffset.y<(142*(i+1)))
        {
            view1Y=(142*i);
            view2Y=284+(142*i);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (scroller.contentOffset.y>=(130*i)&&scroller.contentOffset.y<(130*(i+1)))
        {
            view1Y=(130*i);
            view2Y=260+(130*i);

        }
     }
  }

  if (IS_IPHONE5) {

       view1.frame=CGRectMake(0, view1Y-(offsetY%142), 320, 284);
       view2.frame=CGRectMake(0, view2Y-(offsetY%142), 320, 284);
       view3.frame=CGRectMake(0, 426+view1Y, 320, 284);
       view4.frame=CGRectMake(0, 568+view1Y, 320, 284);
       NSLog(@"the content offset is: %d",offsetY);
   }
  else
  {
    view1.frame=CGRectMake(0, view1Y-(offsetY%130), 320, 260);
    view2.frame=CGRectMake(0, view2Y-(offsetY%130), 320, 260);
    view3.frame=CGRectMake(0, 390+view1Y, 320, 260);
    view4.frame=CGRectMake(0, 520+view1Y, 320, 260);
   } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

what i understood by your code is, you are shifting the images while scrolling and resizing it to when it reaches some specific point as you r doing its top i think, then my friend you r making 4 view and i think there are 3 views at a time shown in screen, what you hav to do is make 5 view instead of making 4 views, and revolve these view and let me know after it, i hope it will work in your case.